# SQL Server - Concatenate 3 different tables matching correspondent ID's of those columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've been on this for hours trying to figure this one out. So I need to concatenate values in a single column based on its ID's.

I have 3 tables named Type, DeliverType and Platform. I need to get all the matching ID's in the table Platform and concatenate all of its values in another column of table Platform.

Example :

```
Table Type           Table DeliverType                  Table Platform
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID | Type            ID    | DeliverType                ID     | TypeID  |  DeliverType
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | TestType1        1    | DeliverType1               9      |   3     |       1
2  | TestType2        2    | DeliverType2               9      |   4     |       2
3  | TestType3        3    | DeliverType3               23     |   2     |       4
4  | TestType4        4    | DeliverType4               23     |   1     |       3
```

These are my tables , I want to return the name of Type, the name of DeliverType and the ID of Platform

Expected Result

```
Table Platform

ID | NamesConcat
9  | TestType1,TestType2,TestType3,DeliverType1,DeliverType2,9
23 | TestType2,TesType3,TestType4,DeliverType3,DeliverType4,23
```

So it has only 1 ID which is 9 and all of the testTypes and DeliverTypes correspondant to that ID in table platform needs to be concat.

Here's my code so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID, 
    SUBSTRING(
        (
            SELECT ','+ d.DeliverType,a.Type  AS [text()]
            FROM dbo.DeliverType d
            INNER JOIN dbo.Type a ON a.ID = p.TypeID
            ORDER BY d.ID
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000) [NamesConcat]
FROM dbo.Platform p
```

Would appreciate some help on this one fellow programmers.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the sample data you show, I don't get the same expected result. I would expect the result:

Table Platform

| ID | NamesConcat |
| --- | --- |
| 9 | TestType3,TestType4,DeliverType1,DeliverType2,9 |
| 23 | TestType1,TestType2,DeliverType3,DeliverType4,23 |

If that is indeed the expected result and you want the strings concatenated by the `Type` first and then by `DeliverType` you can do that with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pmain.ID, 
(
    SELECT t.[Type] + ',' 
    FROM Platform p 
    INNER JOIN Type t ON t.ID = p.TypeID
    WHERE p.ID = pmain.ID 
    ORDER BY t.ID
    FOR XML PATH('')
) + 
(
    SELECT d.DeliverType + ','
    FROM Platform p 
    INNER JOIN DeliverType d ON d.ID = p.DeliverTypeID 
    WHERE p.ID = pmain.ID 
    ORDER BY p.ID
    FOR XML PATH('')
) + 
CAST(pmain.ID AS VARCHAR(10)) AS NamesConcat
FROM Platform pmain
```

If you don't need the concatenated values in that order, you could do it with a shorter query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pmain.ID, 
(
    SELECT d.DeliverType + ',' + t.[Type] + ',' 
    FROM Platform p 
    INNER JOIN DeliverType d ON d.ID = p.DeliverTypeID 
    INNER JOIN Type t ON t.ID = p.TypeID
    WHERE p.ID = pmain.ID 
    FOR XML PATH('')
) + CAST(pmain.ID AS VARCHAR(10)) AS NamesConcat
FROM Platform pmain
```

So that you can check the work, here is a simple script that I wrote to mimic your demo data and the result:

```
DECLARE @Type AS TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    [Type] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @Type([Type]) VALUES('TestType1'), ('TestType2'), ('TestType3'), ('TestType4');

DECLARE @DeliverType AS TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, 
    [DeliverType] VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @DeliverType([DeliverType]) VALUES ('DeliverType1'), ('DeliverType2'), ('DeliverType3'), ('DeliverType4');

DECLARE @Platform AS TABLE (
    ID INT NOT NULL, 
    TypeID INT NOT NULL, 
    DeliverTypeID INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @Platform(ID, TypeID, DeliverTypeID) VALUES (9, 3, 1), (9, 4, 2), (23, 2, 4), (23, 1, 3);

SELECT DISTINCT pmain.ID, 
(
    SELECT d.DeliverType + ',' + t.[Type] + ',' 
    FROM @Platform p 
    INNER JOIN @DeliverType d ON d.ID = p.DeliverTypeID 
    INNER JOIN @Type t ON t.ID = p.TypeID
    WHERE p.ID = pmain.ID 
    FOR XML PATH('')
) + CAST(pmain.ID AS VARCHAR(10)) AS NamesConcat
FROM @Platform pmain

SELECT DISTINCT pmain.ID, 
(
    SELECT t.[Type] + ',' 
    FROM @Platform p 
    INNER JOIN @Type t ON t.ID = p.TypeID
    WHERE p.ID = pmain.ID 
    ORDER BY t.ID
    FOR XML PATH('')
) + 
(
    SELECT d.DeliverType + ','
    FROM @Platform p 
    INNER JOIN @DeliverType d ON d.ID = p.DeliverTypeID 
    WHERE p.ID = pmain.ID 
    ORDER BY p.ID
    FOR XML PATH('')
) + 
CAST(pmain.ID AS VARCHAR(10)) AS NamesConcat
FROM @Platform pmain
```

I hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Thank you very much. Could you please explain the differences between pmain and p? The rest of the code I understood it perfectly.

Comment: Sure! Since we are joining to a subquery, the table Platform is being used twice. We have to alias the table so that SQL Server (or whatever RDBMS) does not get confused. I call the outermost alias pmain (not creative, but there you have it - the Platform table in the main query). In the subqueries I use the alias p (very lazy, I know...). When I join from the main query to the subquery, I want to match the main ID value from Platform (pmain.ID) to the Platform ID in the subquery (p.ID).

Comment: Ohh , I got it now! Thank you very much dude , you really are a lifesaver.